# Deep linking without redirecting to Play Store

Tags: android, deep-linking

**Context:**

We are currently building a custom play store. Since Android's Play Store doesn't host such apps, we provide a webpage with the "Download" button, on click of which the user installs our apk.

**Problem:**

We would like to generate a deep-link for this. If the user hits this deep-link URL, if the app is installed, it will open the app. If the app is not installed, it will open the web page from which you can install the apk.

Can this be done?

Comment: In you question, you want to open in both cases(installed/not installed). What exactly you want to open is app is not installed.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you want to open you Custom Play store app if its installed and launch web page if its not available.

Comment: You are not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To open the app on tap of link you have to add `intent-filter` to one for the app launcher in you `Manifest` file:

```
 <!-- To open app using link -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="yourdomain.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/someurlparam">
    </data>
</intent-filter>
```

If app is available it'll be launched else browsers will do his work.

Answer (score 0):

Branch.io and Google have free services that provide precisely this functionality.

The docs for configuring this using Branch can be found here: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/

Google's deep linking service is part of Firebase and mimics Branch.io's functionality.